# Auto validate fields on different tab on Save of main record on Opportunity

Tags: acumatica

I want to make few fields on Contacts Info tab of Opportunity (Screen ID - CR304000) mandatory so that user has to enter it before saving the main Opportunity record. I saw it is mainly from CRContact and CRAddress. I have created a DAC extension for both and included all the fields to be validated in it. Below is the code for the same.

```cs
public class CROpportunityExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity>
{
    [PXDBGuid(false)]
    [PX.Objects.CR.MassProcess.PXMassUpdatableField]
    [PXOwnerSelector(typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity.workgroupID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Owner", Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual Guid? OwnerID { get; set; }

    [CROpportunityAddress(typeof(Select<Address, Where<True, Equal<False>>>))]
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual int? OpportunityAddressID { get; set; }

    [CROpportunityContact(typeof(Select<Contact, Where<True, Equal<False>>>))]
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual int? OpportunityContactID { get; set; }
}

public class CRContactExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CRContact>
{
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "First Name", Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

    [PXDBString(100, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Name", Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    [PXDBEmail]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Email", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    [PhoneValidation]
    [PXDBString(50)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Phone 1", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string Phone1 { get; set; }
}

public class CRAddressExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CRAddress>
{
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "City", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true)]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string City { get; set; }

    [PXDBString(20)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Postal Code", Required = true)]
    [PXZipValidation(typeof(Country.zipCodeRegexp), typeof(Country.zipCodeMask), typeof(PX.Objects.CR.CRAddress.countryID))]
    [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

However, it is not validating on main record save directly. Instead if I try to save any values in the Contacts info tab then it will validate on main record save. Below are the steps.

1. It do not validate when
   a. Create new opportunity
   b. Fill all the required fields upper part and on details tab
   c. Save the opportunity record.
2. It validates when
   a. Create new opportunity
   b. Fill all the required fields in upper part and on details tab
   c. Fill fields other than required fields on Contacts info tab
   d. Try to save opportunity record. It will validate the mandatory fields on Contacts Info tab.

I need it should validate in 1st case itself. Please suggest.

Comment: It cannot validate the existing records, however it still validates the new records if created and required fields are not entered. Ideal solution is create a GI and update all the required fields for existing records so it do not create any issue. For new records it anyway validates correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot validate the existing records, however it still validates the new records if created and required fields are not entered. Ideal solution is create a GI and update all the required fields for existing records so it do not create any issue. For new records it anyway validates correctly.